# Ruby command line script: Trying to pass variable in switch case

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm creating a ruby command line tool which has a switch case statement, I'd like to pass through variables on this switch case statement for example:

```
  input = gets.chomp
  case input
    when 'help'
      display_help
    when 'locate x, y' # this is the bit i'm stuck on
      find_location(x, y)
    when 'disappear s'
      disappear_timer(s)
    when 'exit'
      exit
    else
     puts "incorrect input"
   end
```

Essentially I want the user to be able to type in `locate 54, 30` or `sleep 5000` and then call a function which handles the number they passed. I was wondering how I can either pass arguments from the user in a switch statement like this for my command line tool like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) matcher inside `when`:

```
when /locate \d+, \d+/
  find_location *input.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
```

Here we basically match whatever is `locate` followed by digits, comma, space, digits. If matched, we extract the digits from the string with [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) and then convert to `Integer`s, finally passing them as an argument to `find_location` method.

Comment: you can use the globals `$1 ..` so you don't have to run the regexp multiple times, like this: `when /locate (\d+), (\d+)/   find_location $1.to_i, $2.to_i`